# Query to check if job already belongs to jobserver in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am working with a legacy migration script that was setup to add a job (with a number of steps) to a SQL Server. I am trying to build in some semblance of re-runable without it completely blowing up.

However I am now down to this line :

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver 
                        @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
```

If the job already belongs to the local server, then this line will error. It's very feasible that this might be run several times.

Is there a query that I could run to check whether a job already belongs to local (Or any other servername?)

Answer (score 3):

Found my solution.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobservers 
              WHERE (job_id = @myJobId AND server_id = 0))
```